# Sing Song - nursery poem definitions

Tags: meaning, slang, poetry

My wife was reading me this poem for our kids' homeschool

> A city plum is not a plum; A dumb-bell is no bell, though dumb; A statesman's rat is not a rat; A sailor's cat is not a cat; A soldier's frog is not a frog;

[Sing Song - Christina Georgina Rossetti](http://books.google.com/books?id=Or1dR91CcesC&lpg=PA12&ots=RIuF2GlPl_&dq=%22statesman%27s%20rat%22&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false)

I know what a dumb bell and a captain's log are (weights and a diary), but what's a city plum; what is a statesman's rat; what is a sailor's cat; and what is a soldier's frog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was *homework?* Apparently this doggerel ditty was [published 1872](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_MRyb4yXwZIC&pg=PT335&dq=%22city%20plum%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XDlxT6y7JM6z8QPo27VW&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22city%20plum%22&f=false) by [Christina Rossetti](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/a-city-plum-is-not-a-plum/)...

1. city *plum* - rare slang for someone who possesses £100000.
2. statesman's *rat* - politician who abandons his party.
3. sailor's *cat* - braided naval whip, 'cat-o-nine-tails' or possibly a type of sailor's knot - a 'cat's paw' or 'catshank'.
4. soldier's *frog* - decorative fastening made of ornamental braiding which loops around a button.

I never heard of *plum* for a rich person, but all the others are still current. Not that I knew about [frog fasteners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_%28fastening%29) until now, and the cat/whip no longer exists in civilised society. Newspapers still sometimes relish reporting political rats, but after all this time they're hardly news any more.

Comment: Wow, that's very interesting (and crazy what they throw in nursery rhymes in the 1800's).  I don't think the definitions were important for the kindergarten curriculum, at least I hope they're not.  But I can just hear my daughter ask, "if a soldier's cat is not a cat, then what is it?".  The book is actually illustrated with a cat with 9 tails, so I had a hankering on that one (not that I knew off hand what a cat-o-nine-tails meant)

Comment: @P. Alan Phillip Turner: Umm... I don't think I'd call it a "nursery rhyme". Probably none of those slang terms would have been considered appropriate for children in Victorian London. But I have to say your choice of kindergarten, and their choice of nursery rhymes, show somewhat exotic tastes!

Comment: Lots of nursery rhymes are alleged to have hidden or second meanings that we no longer think are especially appropriate for children. For example, "According to the Oxford English Dictionary the term 'humpty dumpty' referred to a drink of brandy boiled with ale in the seventeenth century." [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty]

Comment: @JLG: Yes, I thought about that (specifically, ["Ring a Ring o' Roses"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_a_Ring_o'_Roses) and Plague) when I was composing the answer. I shied away from calling it a "nursery rhyme" because it doesn't seem to have a surface-level interpretation appropriate to children, so "doggerel ditty" was the best I could come up with. I think the original target audience was probably the London "tea set/chattering classes" of the day. For today's children it's really just a "tum-ti-tum" rhythmic form with effectively meaningless words.

Comment: For the record, the book is called "[Sing Song: A Nursery Rhyme Book](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486221075.html)" and yeah, half the rhymes seem to be about the death of infants.

Comment: @P. Alan Phillip Turner: Yeah - on reflection some of what I wrote above sounds a bit precious. Nursery rhymes and fairy tales have always had a fair amount of gore & such. What I was really thinking originally was just that you wouldn't expect children to even *care* about things like political turncoats and clothing fasteners (little horrors that they are though, they prolly *would* be fascinated by *the cat* as an instrument of punishment! :)

Comment: I suppose a lot of the rhymes were written to amuse the adults reciting them, more than for the children. Kind of like some of the jokes or gags in "Sesame Street" are intended for the parents watching and go straight over the heads of the children watching. Also, children's deaths were obviously more a fact of life when some of these rhymes were written than they are today.

Comment: @JLG: Agreed. I still think the subject matter of *this* "ditty" more appropriate to adults than children, though I do now see that even the original publication was *"Sing Song: **a Nursery Rhyme-book**"*. But me, I'm with this 1894 opinion - [One searches in vain for a "tuneful" song to sing to little folk. Furthermore, many of the verses are **much too melancholy** to be included in such a collection.](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to+sing+to+little+folk%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't wish to take anything away from FumbleFingers' clear and concise answer, but I think *frog* has more meanings than mentioned.  It could certainly be an ornamental braid, and *gold-frogged uniforms* is quite a common phrase.  But a *frog* is also the term for the fastening on a belt that takes a bayonet or whatever (sometimes *sword-frog*), which seems more likely in contaxt.